# Status Running meaning in "kubectl get pod <pod name>" output

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to write a API to return pod health status considering all the probe checks are successful. I have one quick question, what is the criteria of kubectl get pod status showing "Running"? Will it take care of the all the probes status success (liveness, readiness and startupProbe).

Answer (score 2):

if your container starts successfully status will be running a simple scenario but **probes** manage the **Ready** state.

if any of your probes fail that might can change the status from **ready 1/1** to **0/1**. depends on condition and configuration.

it might possible container or pod status will be in **running** codnition but if your API not successfully returning **200** or **204** to **probes**, POD may not come to a **ready** state for handling user traffic.